# is evolution app available for android

Tags: applications

I was trying to find android [evolution app](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_%28software%29) (originally gnome personal manager application). The only result google gave me was the *monkey->man evolution*. Does anybody know whether somebody has ported evolution to android?

Comment: if you specify what exactly the features from Evolution that you want to have available from Android, I'm sure many would be able to suggest a replacement. The UI required in touchscreen environment is extremely different than the UI required in desktop applications, porting Evolution to android would essentially be creating a new app almost from scratch and there are many other calendar/email clients already available in Android.

Comment: well, apps like evernote are available in different platforms/devices. Before I start to use evolution I want to make sure it will be available also on mobile devices. If it's not, I'll probably stick to evernote.

Comment: Evolution is wholly a desktop software, it doesn't have a server-side component at all; Evolution only speaks in standardized protocols like POP/IMAP, Exchange, iCal, WebDAV, etc (before you ask, yes, there are Android apps capable of talking in these protocols). Evernote, on the other hand, is primarily a service. The nature of the two are *completely* different.

Comment: yep, Evernote offers a backend server, so that each client app can access the same data for an authenticated user. Ok, now I got the difference, thanks. Evolution is not what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never heard it was, and I'm pretty sure if it were I had heard. (Originally "Ximian Evolution", by the way ;) Neither have I heard of something comparable. Mail, Calendar, Todo etc. are available as separate apps, sometimes also in combinations, but then mostly only combinations of calendar + todo, not with mail.

Closest coming is probably [Pocket Informant](http://www.appbrain.com/app/pocket-informant-3/net.webis.pi3) (USD 10), joining calendar, tasks, and contacts:

[image: Pocket Informant 3]
<sup>*Pocket Informant 3* (source: Google Play; click image for larger variant)</sup>

I personally favour a combination of [Business Calendar](http://www.appbrain.com/app/business-calendar/netgenius.bizcal) (bought the Pro), [Business Tasks](http://www.appbrain.com/app/business-tasks/com.appgenix.biztasks) (integrates neatly into their calendar app), and [K-9 Mail](http://www.appbrain.com/app/k-9-mail/com.fsck.k9) instead on my Android devices (and yes, on my Computer I use Evolution).